# How can I convert the column names(task, asset,name,owner) as row and store it in a new .csv file using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

In Python, how can I convert the column names(task, asset,name,owner) as row and store it in a new .csv file ?

```
Data Set (sample_change.csv) : 
task    asset   name        owner
JJJ01   61869   assetdev    hoskot,john (100000)
JJJ02   87390   assetprod   hope, ricky (100235)
JJJ10   28403   assetprod   shaw, adam  (199345)
```

The below is the code I started to write, but couldn't think of an approach.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

#reading csv file and making the data frame
dataframe = pd.read_csv(r"C:\AWSGEEKS\dataset\sample_change.csv")

columns = list(dataframe.head(0))
print(columns)
```

Output :

```
columns
task    
asset   
name        
owner
```

Comment: dataframe.columns will return your columns as a list, could then make a new empty df with the columns and df.to_csv('new.csv') it

Comment: I want to store the individual column names as individual row. So here 4 column names, will get stored as 4 row inside a single column("column_name") @matman9

Answer (score 2):

To write as a single row:

```py
pd.DataFrame(columns=dataframe.columns).to_csv('header.csv')
```

To write as as single column:

```py
pd.DataFrame(dataframe.columns).to_csv('header.csv', index=False, header=['Name'])
```

Comment: I want to store the individual column names as individual row. So here 4 column names, will get stored as 4 row inside a single column("column_name") @ilyankou

Comment: Try this: `pd.DataFrame(dataframe.columns).to_csv('header.csv')`

Comment: It's working but it's creating extra column with index number (0,1,2,3). How can I remove that ? Also the column header of this column is 0. How can I customize that ?

Comment: See edited answer above, and please consider accepting as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dataframe.columns, columns=['column names'])
```